# apache2 and php5-fpm, how to correctly process *.phps files?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, php

I've setup my server using apache2 and php5-fpm, pretty much like in this guide:
http://www.versatilewebsolutions.com/blog/2012/11/installing-apache-2-with-php-fastcgi-on-ubuntu-12-10.html

The only question left is, how can I configure it to correctly process the *.phps files?
I want to show the highlighted code of them.

There are guides for nginx and php-fpm ( https://blog.kamalnasser.net/post/highlighting-phps-files-in-nginx/ ), but what should we do with apache2 ?

Comment: I am looking for this too, but this is old. lol

Answer (score 1):

Caveats: Ubuntu 14.10, Apache/2.4.10

In the file /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    # Deny access to raw php sources by default
    # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
    # only in specific virtual host or directory
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Add a  with "Allow from all" (or something more appropriate to your paranoia-level) to you host config, and you'll be all set.

My config:

```
<Directory /my/very/long/and/winding/server/path/public_html/phpsource/>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Php Source files in other directories get denied, the ones in that  directory gets displayed. It works like a charm...

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Add it to your apache config file. There should be a similar line like this:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

So just add it below.

Comment: It would not work, as there is no thing declared which would process it. As I understand, the solution you've described would work only if you're using the apache2 php handler.